# When launching dawn4.0 on ubuntu 16.04, i got some errors "Error 3110001: Missing Chain API Plugin"

Tags: nodeos

When launching dawn4.0 on ubuntu 16.04, i got some errors "Error 3110001: Missing Chain API Plugin"
this error only happened on ubuntu on dawn4.0, and mac or centos work well.

Comment: have u used plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin option in config file, or launched nodeos with --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin option?

Comment: yes, both of them. and i am sure , i used the name "chain_api_plugin"

Comment: This is a question about a version of EOSIO that is too old to migrate.